# Why is Firefox CPU usage high?

Tags: firefox, cpu-usage

I have uBlock Origin and Privacy Badger installed, in addition to several other add-ons, on both Chrome and Firefox.  Firefox uses much more CPU on Reddit's homepage than does Chrome.  (I do not know if Firefox uses more CPU on other pages yet.)

I tried deactivating all add-ons; the CPU usage remained high.

I tried reinstalling Firefox; the CPU usage remained high.

Any ideas to reduce CPU usage?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was reducing the size of the disk cache. It was 1GB initially but I set it to 50MB. On the about:config page look for *browser.cache.disk.capacity* and set the value you want in KB.

Answer (score 0):

Without any concrete data, all I can offer is general advice for the moment.

Check out [`about:performance`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/task-manager-tabs-or-extensions-are-slowing-firefox) to see how resources are being used by your tabs and browser addons.

If you're still suspicious that something's not right, it may be worth [creating a new blank Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles) for comparison.